# Python and Flask general errors no longer appearing in logs

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

General error that you see, like failing to get a value when you use a non existent key in a dictionary, no longer get put in the logfile now that I'm set up with gunicorn and nginx. I can try/except errors and print them, but I'd like to still just have them appear like when running manually instead of through gunicorn.

My **init**.py that specifies logging

```
    gunicorn_error_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
    if (app.logger.hasHandlers()):
        app.logger.handlers.clear()
    app.logger.handlers.extend(gunicorn_error_logger.handlers)
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    config[config_name].init_app(app)
```

Then when I use it anywhere in the app to log, it works:

```
from flask import current_app
current_app.logger.debug("Register member to DB")
```

This is the start command:

```
/opt/app_name/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/opt/app_name/venv/app_name.sock --log-file /opt/app_name/app_name.log --log-level DEBUG --reload --workers=2 run:app
```

I was expecting the python interpreter's general errors that occur to go in to this log file but if I force an error, it has zero output unless I have try/except block and printed the exception

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create a new logger specifically for Gunicorn
gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')

# Set the logger level to the desired level
gunicorn_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # Adjust the level as needed

# Add the logger to the Flask application's logger handlers
app.logger.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
app.logger.setLevel(gunicorn_logger.level)
```

This code works